# What is the equivalent file of liferay-portlet.xml in liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I want to add custom user notifications in liferay 7. For this If I were using liferay 6.2 I would have to make entries like **user-notification-definitions** and **user-notification-handler-class** in liferay-portlet.xml . But in liferay I want to ask where to put these entries. Please help....thanx in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also find similar properties here :

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/portlet-descriptor-to-osgi-service-property-map

According to above link, user-notification-definitions is not supported though OSGI props.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 2):

You can still use this file in legacy portlets (packaged in WAR files).

For OSGi Components, the settings from that file end up in the properties for your component. Those properties starting with `javax.portlet` mirror the settings from `portlet.xml`, those starting with `com.liferay` mirror those that are documented for `liferay-portlet.xml`

Comment: Thanks Olaf for your reply..Does this mean I have to make entries in liferay-portlet.xml? If yes, where is it located? I can't find it in the portlet. Do I need to make a custom file named liferay-portlet.xml inside my portlet?

Comment: Are you packaging WAR files? : yes. Are you creating OSGi bundles? : no